# What does "local variable" mean in the Forth programming language?

Tags: forth, gforth

In C, local variables exist inside of a function and contain the values like this:

```
void main(){
    int a = 5;
    int b = 9;
}
```

In the Gforth manual, they describe the **local variables** like this:

```
: swap { a b -- b a }
  b a ;
1 2 swap .s 2drop
```

but it seems like a function which is taking two arguments, *a* and *b*.

Another tutorial on the Forth language shows a variable like this:

```
variable a
3 a !    ( ! to store the value )
```

So, which one is correct?

Comment: Probably refresh your terminology. "Local variable" is well-defined in Forth; it's a variable which you declared in `{ ... }` which goes out of scope at the end of the definition. Your other example is not a local variable.

Comment: Right. `variable` declares a _global_ variable. In standard Forth you can't even put a `variable` declaration inside a word definition, so there's not much room for confusion between the two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Forth, local variables are described by the following syntax (see also [13.6.2.2550 `{:`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/locals/bColon)):

`{:`  *args* [ `|`  *vals* ] [ `––` *outs* ]  `:}`

where each of *args*, *vals* and *outs* represents space-delimited names (the parts in square brackets are optional). These names are interpreted as follows:

- *args* names are for locals that are initialized from the data stack, with the top of the stack being assigned to the rightmost name in *args*;
- *vals* names are for locals that are uninitialized;
- *outs* names are ignored (they are for documentation purposes only, if any).

Gforth uses `{ ... }` notation for locals as an alternative to the standard one.

So, `swap` can be defined as:

```
: swap {: a b :} b a ;
```

It takes two values from the stack into `a` and `b` local variables, and then puts them back on the stack in the reversed order.

An example of use an uninitialized local variable:

```
: exch ( x2 addr -- x1 ) {: a | x1 :}
  a @ to x1 a ! x1
;
```

The optional `-- ...`  part is allowed to mimic a stack diagram, i.e., to unite the declaration of locals and the stack diagram for a word. For example:

```
: umin {: u2 u1 -- u2|u1 :} u2 u1 u< if u2 else u1 then ;
```

Without special optimizations, performance of local variables is slightly worse than of a little stack juggling.

Comment: Re *"performance of local variables is slightly worse than of a little stack juggling"*: Can you quantify that? Do you have some measurements? What system was it tested on?