# How can I check whether enough arguments are passed to a word in Forth?

Tags: forth, gforth

I have written this word to multiply two floating point numbers:

```
: fpmult { F: a F: b }
  cr
  ." Result: "
  a b f* f.
;
```

This works fine as long as there are either two fp's on the fstack or the commandline. Even the combination of one fp on the fstack plus one fp in the commandline which launches the word is possible:

```
1.3e  ok
5.78e fpmult 
Result: 7.514  ok
```

But if only one fp is missing it throws an error (of course):

```
5.78e fpmult 
:9: Floating-point stack underflow
5.78e >>>fpmult<<<
Backtrace:
$7F5CDB1367A0 f>l
```

How can I make the word check for the existence of both variables `a` and `b` right at the start? Or is there a better way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [standard word](https://forth-standard.org/standard/float/FDEPTH) `fdepth ( -- u )`

```
: fpmult. ( F: r1 r2 -- )
  fdepth 2 u< if cr ." insufficient number of arguments" abort then
  f* f.
;
```

NB: `abort` empties the data stack and floating-point stack.

---

JFYI, the standard [local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72191233/1300170) syntax is `{: :}`

Comment: To check the stacks using fdepth or depth is quite clean and simple. But to check whether a word has been launched w/ or w/o arguments is still my question. I have tried your suggestion to use the standard local variable syntax {:...:} but this throws only errors in Gforth. So, again the question: How can a word check whether it got a parameter or not? And btw., thx a lot for your time and efforts, I appreciate this a lot <3 !

Comment: I have added an example of how to check if a word is provided with at least two arguments on the floating-point stack.  Re locals — ah, I see. Probably you use **very** old Gforth version.

Comment: I have gforth v0.7.3, but will look for a newer version right now...

Comment: Updated to Gforth 0.7.9_20231102. Then I pasted your example code and ran it w/o parameters. WORKS :) Thanks a lot, I'm one step further now and have to check all my code examples with the new version. Thanks again!

Comment: One last remark: So, the only way to check variables or values, respectively, is to work your way over the stack to use fdepth and depth, right? I have tried code examples with try and catch, but maybe they failed due to the outdated version...

Comment: In Forth, a variable is a named memory region. By this way you don't check a variable, but just the number of arguments (or values) on the stack. Re `catch` — I would not use it for that.